# How can I save an admin credential for use on multiple user accounts?

Tags: windows, administrator, updates, credentials-manager

*I realize that this may not be the best practice security-wise. But This is a very specific scenario and my department has decided this is the best course of action.*

My department is currently in charge of maintaining a few machines that we allow to be used by standard users to interact with a GUI application. This application does not normally require elevated privileges to run, but frequently requires an update in order to run, and updating the application does require elevated privileges.

We have been battling this problem for months, and it is not sustainable to request an admin to come over and input their credentials to allow the update, nor do we have the manpower to manually run updates as this program takes a long time to launch and the update must be initiated from within the application.

We have tried using Scheduled Tasks to launch the application with elevated privileges but schtasks launches the application without GUI which prevents the user from being able to initiate the update from within the application.

After many meetings we have decided to use /savecred to store a local admin login within a batch file to launch the application with elevated privileges and convert the batch file into an EXE to prevent users from editing the shortcut.

The problem we have encountered is that the credential must be saved by entering the admin password once per standard user, this is not feasible as we have many users coming and going, and this would end up taking more time than just entering the password upon request.

Again I am aware that this is an imperfect and somewhat insecure solution, but we have decided it is the best solution for a unique problem.

TL;DR: How can I force a credential saved in Windows Credential Manager to mirror across multiple user accounts without having to enter the password for each account?

Comment: Is there a reason you are not making those users local admins, so they can just use their own account to update? One way or the other, they will have an account with more rights, so it doesn't make sense to create a hack in this case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest a different approach : Let the user run this one
application as administrator without him knowing the
administrator password.

Products that can help:

- [RunAsRob](https://robotronic.net/runasroben.html)
- [RunAsTool](https://www.sordum.org/8727/runastool-v1-5/)
- [Run As GUI](https://web.archive.org/web/20200318075026/https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/Run-As-GUI-b23012b2)
  This link is to the Internet Archives, as the original website
  has disappeared. You need to right-click on the Zip file to download.

Comment: Thank you very much. We ended up going with RunAsTool. Exactly what we needed.